# How to add existing file to ZIP file using RubyZIP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyzip

In my Rails 4.2 application I am using [RubyZIP](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) to create a controller action similar to the following:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def some_action
    file_stream = Zip::ZipOutputStream.write_buffer do |zip|
      zip.put_next_entry "dir1/hello.txt"
      zip.print "Hello"
      zip.put_next_entry "dir2/hello.txt"
      zip.print "World"
    end
    file_stream.rewind
    respond_to do |format|
      format.zip do
        send_data file_stream.read, filename: "zip_file.zip"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

In the example two files are dynamically created and written to, then saved into a ZIP file.

But how can I add a file that already exists (!) to the ZIP file as well, e.g. a PDF file from my `/app/assets/documents` folder?

This should be much easier to achieve but I can't find any documentation on it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you do `zip.put_next_entry "filename"; zip << File.binread("file/path/and/filename")`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks, @matt!

Answer (score 4):

```
zip_file = File.new(zip_file_path, 'w')

Zip::File.open(zip_file.path, Zip::File::Create) do |zip|
  zip.add(file_name, file_path)
end

zip_file
```

Here, file_name and file_path are name and paths of the file you want to add to your zip file and zip_file_path is the path of ZipFile. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. This did indeed work but creates the files on disc which is not necessary in my case.

Comment: You can delete the file later after use.